# How can I improve the performance of multiple SQL queries from dbt to Snowflake?

Tags: sql, scripting, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

Within my dbt scripts  I need to run a few SQL commands that don't need to feed into something else (for example db cloning, permission setting, etc).

How can I improve the performance of running multiple little queries?

Comment: are you wanting them to run in serial or parallel? Given you mention "not feeding into other things" and performance? Or the "other things" meaning as a block they need to be done in order, but there are no other DBT steps chained off them?

Comment: In part I was fishing for Josh answer, as it's a pretty cool pattern that can be useful to others - and he deserves the credits. Happy to hear of alternatives!

Comment: I have almost the same question to Josh's answer, but thought I would first see what you were after..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your dbt model, you can use a [anonymous block](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/blocks.html#using-an-anonymous-block). This allows you to run multiple queries inside of a single call.

To do this, use [run_query](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_query) with dbt, surrounding your code with `begin` and ending with `end; $$`.

Example:

```sql
{% set query %}
    begin
    -- lots of queries that don't really do anything special here, like db cloning or whatever --
    select 1;
    select 2;
    select 3;
    end;
    $$
{% endset %}
{% do run_query(query) %}
```